# GraphicsMagick new a image on the fly

Tags: graphicsmagick

I am using the **GraphicsMagick Wand** to process images. I don't know how to new a image on the fly. I don't how to do it. There isn't any demo on the [Doc](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/wand/magick_wand.html)
Now, I just load a **1px** png image to temporarily solve it. I don't want load a image each time. It seems not the best solution.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I think it will help others. So I answer my question.
First, You need use **MagickReadImage** method to read a string **XC:**
`MagickReadImage(intern->magick_wand, "XC:")`

Then, set image size by using **MagickScaleImage** method:
`MagickScaleImage(intern->magick_wand, columns, rows)`

At last, set the format:
`MagickSetImageFormat(intern->magick_wand, format)`